# How to escape single quotes correctly creating an alias

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias, escape-characters

I've been given this one-liner to know how much memory my processes consume.

```
$ ps -u $USER -o pid,rss,command | \
    awk '{print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}'
```

Now I'd like to create an alias for that command, but have an issue escaping `'` characters:

```
$ alias mm=ps -u $USER -o pid,rss,command | \
    awk '{print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}'
bash: alias: -u: not found
bash: alias: myuser: not found
bash: alias: -o: not found
bash: alias: pid,rss,command: not found
Total 0 MB
```

I tried to escape the single quotes, but still it doesn't work.

```
$ alias mm='ps -u $USER -o pid,rss,command | \
    awk \'{print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}\''
>
```

Can you help me understand how to create this alias?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/41861

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To make this an alias, which is possible, you need to use double quotes around the entire value for the alias. You'll also need to escape a few things within the alias as a result, and you need to escape any of the field arguments to `awk` since these will get interpreted as arguments by Bash as well when you're setting the alias.

This worked for me:

```
$ alias mm="ps -u $USER -o pid,rss,command | \
    awk '{print \$0}{sum+=\$2} END {print \"Total\", sum/1024, \"MB\"}'"
```

In the above I've done the following:

1. Double quotes around alias' value

   ```
   alias mm="ps -u ...."
   ```
2. Escaped awk's double quotes

   ```
   awk '{print \$0}{sum+=\$2} END {print \"Total\", sum/1024, \"MB\"}
   ```
3. Escaped awk's fields

   ```
   awk '{print \$0}{sum+=\$2} END
   ```

#### Would I use this?

Probably not, I'd switch this to a Bash function instead, since it'll be easier to maintain and understand what's going on, but here's the alias if you still want it.

Answer (score 16):

> Can you help me understand how to create this alias?

May I advise you to create a function if you use bash and put it in .bashrc?

```
mm() {
  ps -u "$USER" -o pid,rss,command |
    awk '{print $0}{sum+=$2}
         END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}'
}
```

If it's `bash`, variables need to be quoted. In a function, no need to put everything on one line.

Answer (score 8):

Here is escaped command:

```
alias mm='ps -u $USER -o pid,rss,command | \
    awk '\''{print $0}{sum+=$2} END {print "Total", sum/1024, "MB"}'\'
```

Example of escaping quotes in shell:

```
$ echo 'abc'\''abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"\""abc"
abc"abc
```

It's simply done by finishing already opened one (`'`), placing escaped one (`\'`), then opening another one (`'`).

Alternatively:

```
$ echo 'abc'"'"'abc'
abc'abc
$ echo "abc"'"'"abc"
abc"abc
```

It's done by finishing already opened one (`'`), placing quote in another quote (`"'"`), then opening another one (`'`).

Related: [How to escape single-quotes within single-quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/55075) at stackoverflow SE